# Custom JSP tag - How do I get the body of the tag?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

I have a custom jsp tag like this:

```
<a:customtag>
    The body of the custom tag...
    More lines of the body...
</a:customtag>
```

In the custom tag, how can I get the text of what the body is?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's complicated because there are two mechanisms.

If you're extending SimpleTagSupport, you get [getJspBody()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/SimpleTagSupport.html#getJspBody%28%29) method. It returns a JspFragment that you can [invoke(Writer writer)](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/SimpleTagSupport.html#getJspBody%28%29) to have the body content written to the writer.

You should use SimpleTagSupport unless you have a specific reason to use BodyTagSupport (like legacy tag support) as it is - well - simpler.

If you **are** using classic tags, you extend BodyTagSupport and so get access to a [getBodyContent()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/BodyTagSupport.html#getBodyContent%28%29) method. That gets you a BodyContent object that you can retrieve the body content from.

Comment: It's worth noting that a JspFragment is less powerful because it is limited - it must be scriptless, where as a BodyContent is not limited in this way. A BodyContent is in essence like an internal JSP page.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using a custom tag with jsp 2.0 approach, you can do it as:

**make-h1.tag**

```
<%@tag description="Make me H1 " pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>   
<h1><jsp:doBody/></h1>
```

Use it in JSP as:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
<t:make-h1>An important head line </t:make-h1>
```

Comment: If I try to use this approach, I have a problem when the body contains other tags - if I replace `An important head line` with `<t:MyMessageTag key="someKey">` the `<jsp:doBody />`seems to replace it with lower-case `<t:mymessagetag key="someKey">` and won't evaluate that jsp-tag. Any idea why? Or how to handle this kind of nested tags?

Comment: Nested tag should  work with no problem. Ask it as new question may help !

Comment: My mistake was to declare `body-content` attribute as `tagdependent` instead of the default `scriptless` - now everything's fine.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on [Brabster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502282/custom-jsp-tag-how-do-i-get-the-body-of-the-tag/2502370#2502370), I've used `SimpleTagSupport.getJspBody()` to write the `JspFragment` to an internal `StringWriter` for inspection and manipulation:

```
public class CustomTag extends SimpleTagSupport {
    @Override public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
        final JspWriter jspWriter = getJspContext().getOut();
        final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        final StringBuffer bodyContent = new StringBuffer();

        // Execute the tag's body into an internal writer
        getJspBody().invoke(stringWriter);

        // (Do stuff with stringWriter..)

        bodyContent.append("<div class='custom-div'>");
        bodyContent.append(stringWriter.getBuffer());
        bodyContent.append("</div>");

        // Output to the JSP writer
        jspWriter.write(bodyContent.toString());
    }
}
```

}