# How can I make a custom JSP tag that uses other JSP tags?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I would like to write a custom JSP tag whose output includes other JSP tags which should themselves also be dynamically evaluated. But apparently everything that my `TagSupport` subclass writes to `pageContext.getOut()` just goes straight to the client without any further evaluation.

I have a feeling this should be very simple, since it seems like one of the very first things one would want to use custom tags for: encapsulating and reusing other custom tags, avoiding code duplication.

How do I make the following code do what it obviously wants to do?:

```
public class MyTag extends TagSupport {
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
        try {
            pageContext.getOut().println(
              "The output from this tag includes other tags " +
              "like <mypackage:myOtherTag>this one</mypackage:myOtherTag> " +
              "which should themselves be evaluated and rendered."
            )
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new JspException(e);
        }
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }   
}
```

Edit: Some background on my particular use case, if it helps. I have a custom tag `<user>` which dynamically renders a user name in a way that is useful for my application (mouse-hover for first name, last name, phone number, etc.). I'm now writing another tag `<comment>` for displaying user comments, and I would like to use my existing `<user>` tag for rendering user names in the output of the `<comment>` tag.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502282/custom-jsp-tag-how-do-i-get-the-body-of-the-tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split your classes into a tag class and a `tagRenderer` class.

In your situation there would be two new classes called `CommentTagRenderer` and `UserTagRenderer`.

Here is an example of the new `CommentTag`

```
public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
    JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut(); 
    Comment comment = getComment();
    User user =  getUser();

    CommentTagRenderer commentRenderer = new CommentTagRenderer(out);
    UserTagRenderer userRenderer = new UserTagRenderer(out);

    try {
        commentRenderer.renderComment(comment);
        userRenderer.renderUser(user);          
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //some error handling
    }
    return SKIP_BODY;
  }
```

And here is an example of the `CommentTagRenderer`

```
private Writer out;
public CommentTagRenderer(Writer out) {
    this.out = out;
}

public void renderComment(Comment comment) throws IOException {
    out.write("<div>");
    out.write(comment.getComment());
    out.write("</div>");
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar -- a getHTML() method which the tag itself used to generate its output, and which other tags could use to embed that same output in their own output. I guess it is good to know that there's really no other way (without getting into tag files).

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way is to write your custome tag as a JSP tag file, rather than in Java. This way, the new tag can use other custom tags easily. Create a file myTag.tag in /WEB-INF/tags, and use the following code:

```
<%@ tag %>
<%@ attribute name="value" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" type="java.lang.String"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="mypackage" uri="mypackage.tld" %>
The output from this tag includes other tags 
like <mypackage:myOtherTag>${value}</mypackage:myOtherTag>
which should themselves be evaluated and rendered.
```

More information about tag files here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html

Comment: This is good to know, though I neglected to mention in my question that using tag files wasn't an option in my particular case (I'm actually adding features to a large, pre-existing project that has to run on an older JDK without tag file support). I'll up-vote you, though, because this is a valid solution in general!