# JSP custom tag attribute contains a custom tag

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I want to write some code which takes a jsp tag whose attribute itself another jsp tag. for example :

```
<my: image path="<my: imagepath value='abc'/>" />
```

I want the image's path attribute to be dynamically filled by another custom tag imagepath whose value is abc. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971617/how-can-i-make-a-custom-jsp-tag-that-uses-other-jsp-tags) existing solution useful ??

Comment: I saw the answer but I did not understand how is he getting the comment object from the following code public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
    JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut(); 
    Comment comment = getComment();
    User user =  getUser();

    CommentTagRenderer commentRenderer = new CommentTagRenderer(out);
    UserTagRenderer userRenderer = new UserTagRenderer(out);

    try {
        commentRenderer.renderComment(comment);
        userRenderer.renderUser(user);          
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //some error handling
    }
    return SKIP_BODY;
  }

Comment: Why dont you like to use <my:image path="${my:imagepath('abc')}" />?

Comment: <my:image path="${my:imagepath('abc')}" /> did not work.